# How to get data from json, it have multiple json array

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how to get data from Json which have multiple array. I am new to android

This is my Json code :

```
[
    {
        "id": "17",
        "name": "dummy1",
        "com": [
            {
                "user": "ijas",
                "comment": "thanQ test2"
            },
            {
                "user": "sam",
                "comment": "test1"
            },
            {
                "user": "sam",
                "comment": "thanQ test1"
            },
            {
                "user": "ijas",
                "comment": "test2"
            },
            {
                "user": "deepak",
                "comment": "thanQ test3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You could use Gson or Jackson. Search on google it's fairly easy to use

Comment: okay, can you send me the code that i require to fetch the data

Comment: With these libs you don't need to fetch manualy. It allows you to directly instanciate using annotations inside your data model. You can find examples all over the internet https://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON

Answer (score 0):

Here is your json parsed version with GSON.

```
package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Com {

@SerializedName("user")
@Expose
private String user;
@SerializedName("comment")
@Expose
private String comment;

/**
*
* @return
* The user
*/
public String getUser() {
return user;
}

/**
*
* @param user
* The user
*/
public void setUser(String user) {
this.user = user;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The comment
*/
public String getComment() {
return comment;
}

/**
*
* @param comment
* The comment
*/
public void setComment(String comment) {
this.comment = comment;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("com")
@Expose
private List<Com> com = new ArrayList<Com>();

/**
*
* @return
* The id
*/
public String getId() {
return id;
}

/**
*
* @param id
* The id
*/
public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The name
*/
public String getName() {
return name;
}

/**
*
* @param name
* The name
*/
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

/**
*
* @return
* The com
*/
public List<Com> getCom() {
return com;
}

/**
*
* @param com
* The com
*/
public void setCom(List<Com> com) {
this.com = com;
}

}
```

You can use this link : `http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter the number of JSON Arrays or JSON Objects inside a single JSON Object. As it always has a key mapped to the left side of the value.
In the sample you provided has a JSON Array named **com**, you can parse that using the following,

```
 JSONObject resultJSON=new JSONObject(responseString);
    try {
         JSONArray comJSONArray=resultJSON.getJSONArray("com");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Better you can follow like others answered. Use Gson with the POJO class, so that you don't have to write all these code to parse the json

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view i am posting below code to retrieve data from Json String

```
private void GetJson(String jsonString) {
        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
                    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    Log.e("ID", String.valueOf(id));
                    Log.e("NAME", name);

                    String jsonCom = jsonObject.getString("com");

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonCom);
                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {

                        JSONObject objCom = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        String user = objCom.getString("user");
                        String comment = objCom.getString("comment");

                        Log.e("USER", user);
                        Log.e("COMMENT", comment);

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

If you used ASYNK task to retrieve data from WebService then call GetJson("Your json") in onPostMehod() method,
and if you used Volly to retrive data then you need to call our GetJson("json string") in

```
 @Override
public void onResponse(String response) {

     GetJson(response);

 }
```

Comment: if you are happy with my answer than you can give correct answer or vote up me,so any other phase this problem next time it will help to other.